# Contractive family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

**Problem**

Let $\{K_{\alpha}:C\to C\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}$ be a family of functions where $C\subset X$ is a closed subset of a Banach space X. Suppose that for some $\theta \in (0,1)$ we have that $\| K_{\alpha}(x) - K_{\alpha}(y)\| \leq \theta \| x-y\|$ and $K_{\alpha}(x)$ is continuous for some fixed x. Lets call $\overline{x} \in C $ the unique fixed point of $K_{\alpha}$ (the contraction).

**Show that the function $\alpha \to \overline{x}$ is continous.**

Im totally lost in this one, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance guys <3

Comment: What is the domain of the function $\alpha \to \overline{x}$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ I suppose sir

Comment: Can you explain the hypothesis " $K_\alpha$ is continuous for some x fixed"?

Comment: $K_{\alpha}$ is continuous at that point, x.

Comment: Do you mean "there is some point $x \in C$ such that the function $\alpha \mapsto K_\alpha(x)$ is continuous? "

Comment: The problem was presented to me as I wrote it, but maybe it is like you said. Makes more sense

Comment: Since $\| K_{\alpha}(x) - K_{\alpha}(y)\| \leq \theta \| x-y\|$, the function $K_{\alpha}$ is continuous on $C$ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote the unique  fixed point of $K_{\alpha}$ by $f(\alpha).$

Counterexample: $C=X= \mathbb R, n=1$ and

$K_{\alpha}(x)= \frac{\alpha}{2}x$, if $| \alpha |<1$ and $K_{\alpha}(x)= \frac{1}{2 \alpha}(1-x)$, if $| \alpha | \ge 1$. In this case we have $ \theta=1/2$ and

$f(\alpha)=0$, if $| \alpha |<1$ and $f(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2 \alpha +1}$, if $| \alpha | \ge 1$.

$f$ is not continuous !

Comment: Nice counterexample! Also, the function $\alpha \mapsto K_\alpha(\frac{1}{2})$ is continuous. In other words, "$K_\alpha(\frac{1}{2})$ is continuous ".